# HTML5 Canvas clearRect not working with beginPath and closePath

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Im using HTML5 to draw on canvas. I have an array of points in which i loop through to change the x and y coordinates each cycle of draw. What i have now is the dots moving but not clearing the old one, so just lines moving across instead of dots. I looked up other answers which said that i need to use the beginPath with clearRect but that doesn't work. Is there something wrong with the placement of the clearRect can someone help me with this canvas stuff.

```
    draw: function () {
        var ctx = this.context;
        if(this.isReady){
            var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
                var point = this.points[i];
                    var ic = this.calculateGravity(point.x, point.y);
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.cw, this.ch);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(point.x - ic.nX, point.y - ic.nY, point.radius, 0, PI2);
                ctx.fillStyle= point.color;
                ctx.strokeStyle= point.color;
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.stroke();
                this.points[i].x = point.x - ic.nX;
                this.points[i].y = point.y - ic.nY;
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clear your canvas just before rendering your points:

```
if(this.isReady){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.cw, this.ch);
    var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
    /* ... */
}
```